# How to show the measure of the following intersection is positive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I can prove the first part of the following problem using Fubini's Theorem and applying the "translation invariance" property of the Lebesgue measure. [image].

I'm having trouble with the second part of the problem. I suppose I must argue that the intersection is not empty and it contains uncountably many points. If I understand correctly, how should I begin my defense? What should be my argument if not?  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: The lhs is equal to the rhs, hence $>0.$ But the lhs is also equal to $\int_{\Bbb R}m(B\cap(A+x))dx.$

Comment: By Fubini's theorem $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbb{1}_{B}(x)\mathbb{1}_{A+x}(y) dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_B(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{A+x}(y)\,dy\Big)dx=\int\mathbb{1}_B(x)m(A)\,dx=m(B)m(A)$. The last part follows by the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure. As $m(A)m(B)>0$, it follows that $\mathbb{1}_B(y)\mathbb{1}_A(y-x)$ is positive in a set of positive measure. The rest follows by regularity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks! I was thinking the wrong way.

Comment: @OliverDíaz, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @OliverDíaz The 1st part of your comment is about another integral than that of the OP  because you wrote $1_B(x)$ instead of $1_B(y).$ Never mind since the OP already had "proved the first part of the problem using [the same arguments]". As for the second part of your comment, I cannot follow it (the positivity of the function on a set of positive measure and the regularity). The solution is much simpler (cf my comment above).